# What happens step-by-step (and why) when a particle tries to escape an infinite potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

I am aware that the following question might be quite elementary. My background is mainly in mathematics and my physics education is limited to high-school level material (discounting analogues made in calculus courses). I would like to know what happens step-by-step (and why), when a free particle tries to escape an infinite potential well.

As an example consider the 1D scenario described [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Modern_Physics/Book%3A_Spiral_Modern_Physics_(D%27Alessandris)/6%3A_The_Schrodinger_Equation/6.2%3A_Solving_the_1D_Infinite_Square_Well). Reason given by the author on why the particle cannot enter the infinite potential is that no particle can have infinite energy. While, depending on how things are defined/assumed, this might be valid answer, I still suspect that there is some conservation of energy/"particle wants to reside in low potential" type argument. I might be entirely wrong in the sense that the argument really does stop at the point where you try to have a particle with an infinite energy, but then again as my knowledge to the physical assumptions/models/terminology is weak, I am at a point where I do not know precisely what to ask for.

Comment: Define 'tries'. Did you mean finite rather than infinite well?

Comment: @Qmechanic Ah, good point. By "tries" I mean that the free particle moves in a straight line to the boundary of the well. I am interested in knowing the why and the what when a collision occurs.

Comment: If it's actually that what you want, the solution is really easy:  Take the general form of a time-dependent wave function $\psi(t,x) = \sum_n c_n \phi_n(x) \exp(-i E_n t/\hbar)$  in the infinite well with the eigenfunctions $\phi_n(x) = \sqrt{2/L} \sin n \pi x/L$ living in $x \in [0,L]$ and $E_n =\hbar^2 n^2 \pi^2/ 2 m L^2$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$). Determine the expansion coefficients $c_n$ choosing your favourite initial condition $\psi(0,x)$ (suggestion: take e.g. $c_{1,2} \ne 0$ and $c_n=0$ for $n=3,4,\ldots$). Watch the behaviour of $|\psi(t,x)|^2$ as time evolves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite well potential should be regarded as an (idealized) limiting case of the  finite well potential

$V(x) = \begin{cases} V_0 \, \, \, \text{for} \, \, x<0 \\
0 \, \, \, \, \, \, \text{for}  \, \, {0 \le x \le L} \\
V_0 \, \, \, \text{for} \, \, x> L\end{cases}$

with $V_0 > 0$.
The spectrum of the corresponding Hamiltonian $H = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$ consists of discrete energy eigenvalues $0 < E_1 < E_2 < \ldots < V_0$ and a continuous spectrum $\sigma_{\rm c} = [V_0, \infty)$.

The energy eigenfunctions (bound state wave functions) $\phi_n(x)$, being normalizable solutions of the eigenvalue equation $(H \phi_n)(x) =E_n \phi_n(x)$, behave as $\phi_n(x) \sim  e^{-\kappa_n x}$ for $x> L$ and $\phi_n(x) \sim e^{\kappa_n x}$ for $x<0$, where $\kappa_n=\sqrt{2m (V_0-E_n)}/\hbar$. Being in contrast to the situation in classical mechanics, there is thus a non-vanishing probability to find a particle with energy $E< V_0$ in the region of a non-vanishing potential ($x<0$ and $x>L$, respectively).

On the other hand, the solutions of the eigenvalue equation $H \phi_E = E \phi_E$ for $E>V_0$ (i.e. $E \in \sigma_c$) are non-normalizable eigenfunctions of $H$, corresponding to "scattering states". These wave functions behave as $    e^{\pm ik x}$ with $k=\sqrt{2m (E-V_0)}/\hbar$ in the region where $x<0$ or $x>L$. As in the classical case, a particle with energy $E>V_0$ can enter the region where $V(x) =V_0$, however (in contrast to classical mechanics), there is a non-vanishing probability that the particle is reflected (scattered) at $x=0$ or $x=L$.

How can a particle escape a finite potential well? Suppose it is initially in a bound state with energy $E=E_n < V_0$. Clearly, an energy $\epsilon$ of at least $\epsilon \ge V_0-E_n$ is needed to kick it into the continuum.

As an infinite well should be interpreted as the limiting case $V_0 \to \infty$ of the finite well potential, the answer to your question is now obvious. As also the continuous spectrum "escapes" to infinity in this limit, the particle cannot "escape" as large as $\epsilon$ may be. At the same time, because of $\lim\limits_{V_0 \to \infty} e^{-\kappa_n x} = 0$ for $x>L$ (and $\lim\limits_{V_0 \to \infty} e^{\kappa_n x} =0$ for $x<0$), the particle becomes completely confined to the region $[0,L]$, justifying the usual boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$ in the text-book treatment of the infinite well problem.

Answer (score 3):

The task here is to solve Schroedinger's equation.

If you look at the equation you'll see the only way it can possibly work is if the ψ(x) is 0 in the places where U(x) is infinity. Hence the particle isn't outside the well. There is no "the particle tries to escape the well". The particle simply isn't outside the well. That is what the equation says.

This is the time-independent Schroedinger equation. There is also the time-dependent version, which will also have solutions that look like the wavefunction is moving left and right, bouncing between the walls. Wikipedia has animations:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/StationaryStatesAnimation.gif]

Again, though, there is no "tries to escape". There is just "the particle is most likely to be on the left and then it's most likely to be on the right and then it's most likely to be on the left."