# Why is probability outside the infinite square well zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

In an infinite square well, potential energy is given below, why is the probability of finding a particle in the position of infinite potential energy zero?

$$V(x)=\begin{cases}
   0,& \text{if } x \ \text{in}\ (-a,a) \\
    \infty,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The usual explanation is that because at the boundaries, $-a$ and a, the change in potential energy is infinite, making the force as well, causing the particle to stay in the well. But this explanation seems very classical to me (I mean we are explicitly talking about force on a particle which, I believe has no basis in quantum mechanics, except for maybe via Ehrenfest's theorem, but that's not what we are talking about here. I may be grossly wrong about this though).

So how to justify saying that probability outside the well is zero, without resorting to any classical assumptions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens step-by-step (and why) when a particle tries to escape an infinite potential well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744589/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the well is sufficiently deep to bind the particle, the wavefunction decays exponentially outside the well. The rate of exponential decay depends on the depth of the well. For an infinitely deep well, the decay is infinitely fast, so the amplitude is zero outside the well.

Comment: After reading this I realized that I should have had just taken the limit $V(x)\rightarrow \infty$ in the finite square well case. Thank you for the answer.